# Magento2 Add To Cart before plugin not working: 2.4.6

Tags: magento2

my plugin does not work. I am unable to load products onto the cart There are no errors in the error log.

**My Di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
        <type name="Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart">
            <plugin name="addingProductToCart"
                    type="Example\Test\Plugin\Model\Checkout\Cart\Plugin"
                    sortOrder="10"
                    disabled="false"/>
        </type>
    </config>
```

**my Plugin**

```
public function beforeAddProduct($product,$request)
    {
        try {

            // Your custom code here.
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            throw new LocalizedException(__($e->getMessage()));
        }

        return [$product, $request];
    }
```

Please note, a lot of the tutorials return 3 params, but the current cart class only return two:

> vendor/magento/module-checkout/Model/Cart.php

```
class Cart extends DataObject implements CartInterface
{
     public function addProduct($productInfo, $requestInfo = null)
        {
            $product = $this->_getProduct($productInfo);
            $productId = $product->getId();
          ......
    $this->_eventManager->dispatch(
                'checkout_cart_product_add_after',
                ['quote_item' => $result, 'product' => $product]
            );
            $this->_checkoutSession->setLastAddedProductId($productId);
            return $this;

    }

}
```

Comment: Kindly check Rahul's answer. I have already used the below code and it's working fine. I have the same answer so not adding my answer.

Answer (score 1):

In this example, we will define a plugin class that observed function addProduct($productInfo, $requestInfo = null) of a Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart class. addProduct method call each and every time when we add product to cart.In this example, we will change product quantity during add to cart.

Step-1: Create **di.xml** at **`Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml`**. This is declaration of plugin.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
     <type name="Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart">
     <plugin name="productcart" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Productcart" sortOrder="1" />
 </type>
```

Step-2: Create **Productcart.php** as plugin class at **Vendor\Module\Plugin\Productcart.php** and addProduct method written as beforeAddProduct method in plugin class.

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin;

class Productcart
{
    public function beforeAddProduct(
                    \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $subject,
                    $productInfo,
                    $requestInfo = null
            ) {
        
                $requestInfo['qty'] = 5; // increasing quantity to 5
                return array($productInfo, $requestInfo);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please define the plugin in your di.xml

```
<type name="Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart">
   <plugin name="add_to_cart_plugin" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\BeforeAddToCart"/>
</type>
```

Now define your plugin class

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin;

use Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart;

class BeforeAddToCart
{
    public function beforeAddProduct(Cart $subject, $productInfo, $requestInfo = null)
    {
        (execute your code...)

        return [$productInfo,$requestInfo];
    }
}
```

Please try this and let me know if any issues.

Comment: i think your code is old and incorrect. the Cart is deprecated. Also its now two params, not three

Comment: ok i will send you updated code with testing.

Comment: Thanks. please. i am using the latest magento version 2.4.6